# After the channel is created, it takes 1000+ms to transition from IDEL state to CONNECTING state.How can i reduce the time required to change state?

Tags: java, grpc, channel

#### JAVA Code

```
            channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(param.getTarget()).build();
            long channelStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
            asyncStub = ASRRouteGrpc.newStub(channel);
            asrResponseStreamObserver = new ASRResponseStreamObserver(speechTranscriberListener);
            requestObserver = asyncStub.route(asrResponseStreamObserver);
            RouteRequest requestConf = newRequestHead(param);
            traceId = requestConf.getAsrConfig().getTraceId();
            ConnectivityState currentChannelState = channel.getState(true);
            while (currentChannelState != ConnectivityState.READY) {
                CountDownLatch latchUntilChannelReady = new CountDownLatch(1);
                channel.notifyWhenStateChanged(currentChannelState, latchUntilChannelReady::countDown);
                latchUntilChannelReady.await();
                currentChannelState = channel.getState(true);
                if (currentChannelState == ConnectivityState.CONNECTING) {
                    long channelConnecting = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    LOGGER.info("The transition from idle state to connecting takes: {} ms", channelConnecting - channelStart);
                }
            }
            long channelReady = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (LOGGER.isInfoEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.info("Trace id: {}, channel start time: {}, channel ready time: {}, creating channel takes: {} ms", traceId, channelStart, channelReady,
                        channelReady - channelStart);
            }
```

#### LOGGER

```
2023-08-22 14:12:34,816 INFO  client.ASRClient - The transition from idle state to connecting takes: 1009 ms
2023-08-22 14:12:34,841 INFO  client.ASRClient - Trace id: 6afd2c67-e8c5-4cea-bd5c-4b82591a52aa, channel start time: 1692684753807, channel ready time: 1692684754841, creating channel takes: 1034 ms
```

#### Description

##### code logic

1. first create channel
2. mark a time stamp(channelStart) after the channel is created
3. get the state of channel ,the state is IDEL
4. when the state of channel changes from IDEL to CONNECTING,mark a time stamp(channelConnecting)
5. when the state of channel changes from CONNECTING to READY, mark a time stamp(channelReady)

##### Log info

1. It takes 1009ms for channel from IDLE state to CONNECTING state.
2. It takes 25ms for channel from CONNECTIONG state to READY state.

#### What's i supposed

1. Does it take too long for a channel to change from IDLE to CONNECTING?
2. I want to reduce the time it takes for a channel to go from IDLE to CONNECTING.

Comment: Can you time the _second_ channel creation? You can use that same code, but after the first channel shut it down and create a second channel. Java is very slow to start; much of that time will just be class loading. 1s is pretty long for class loading, but if you had a slow filesystem or a slow machine it is conceivable (e.g, if running on a Raspberry Pi).

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
1. What is my enviroment?
MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019) 
2.6 GHz 六核Intel Core i7
16 GB 2667 MHz DDR4
2. First time:
The transition from idle state to connecting takes: 3377 ms,
The transition from idle state to ready takes: 3679 ms
3. Second time:
The transition from idle state to connecting takes: 1643 ms,
The transition from idle state to ready takes: 1797 ms
4.Third time:
The transition from idle state to connecting takes: 1019 ms,
The transition from idle state to ready takes: 1049 ms

Comment: So the first channel was much slower, but the later ones were surprisingly still slow. Looking into things, I found [a bug](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/10517). The transition from IDLE→CONNECTING for a new channel is delayed by the DNS resolution. So it looks like on your network it takes 1-2s for DNS and 1-2s for TCP connections to be created. As far as speeding that up, it'd be important to know the round-trip time (ping time) to the destination and what sort of network this is on.